# How can I fix this if-then structure to break out of the loop as needed?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

The problem I seek to solve is a game of cups. The user enters a string with no spaces of a series of connected A's, B's, and C's. An example is "AB" or "ABBBCABA". The game is that the player moves the cup of the letter selected. The prize begins in position 1, or the leftmost cup. Here is a picture that helps visualize the movements.

[movement picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B72mC.png)

An example move entered "AB" should output 3. An example move of "BC" should output 3.

My code is giving incorrect numbers but I can't figure out where I went wrong logically.

```
import java.io.*;

public class trik {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = reader.readLine();
        int position = 1;
        if (s.length() == 1) { // A
            if (s.contains("A")) {
                System.out.println(2);
            }
            if (s.contains("B")) {
                System.out.println(1);
            }
            if (s.contains("C")) {
                System.out.println(3);
            }
        } else {
            String[] parts = s.split("");
            int i = 0;
            while (i < parts.length) {
                if (parts[i].equals("A")) {
                    if (position != 3) {
                        if (position == 1) {
                            position = 2;
                        }
                        if (position == 2) {
                            position = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (parts[i].equals("B")) {
                    if (position != 1) {
                        if (position == 2) {
                            position = 3;
                        }
                        if (position == 3) {
                            position = 2;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (parts[i].equals("C")) {
                    if (position != 2) {
                        if (position == 1) {
                            position = 3;
                        }
                        if (position == 3) {
                            position = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println(position);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code

```
if (position == 1) {
    position = 2;
}
if (position == 2) {
    position = 1;
}
```

if position was in fact `1` then the code is doing

```
 1 -> 2
```

then

```
 2 -> 1
```

I am thinking that you need an else

```
if (position == 1) {
    position = 2;
}
else if (position == 2) {
    position = 1;
}
```

Personally I would have used a `for` loop, and then when the action has been done, you could simply do a `continue` to return to the top of your loop.

Comment: This above fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Great, please consider to upvote and accept this answer.